# How should I create a modal window that can be reused across a CanJS application?

Tags: canjs

I have an application in which I'd like to create a single modal that retains its data any time it is accessed from anywhere in my application. The modal will display an image library and should be opened any time an image is clicked in the application.

What is the best way to structure this?

Comment: I think you could improve this question by asking something more like "How to create and communicate with a modal window with CanJS".

Comment: Does your modal need to do different things based on from where in the page it's launched?  If not, you can just use pure Bootstrap decorations.